# Laravel validation required_without_all

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Call me stupid, but I can't get it :)
I want to set up validator rule, so it will pass only if one of the two fields is present (adgroup or all_adgroups).

Here is my controller:

```
 $this->validate($request,
        [
            'new_target_cpa_value' => 'required|numeric',
            'adgroups' => 'exists:google.ad_groups,id|required_without_all:all_agroups',
            'all_agroups' => 'required_without_all:adgroups'
        ]
    );
    dd($request->all());
```

Here is dd:

`"_token" => "aHjluUXPuZpEbglmVt4UePhriGvRWDOjk3OgfF88"
  "new_target_cpa_value" => "123"
  "adgroups" => array:1 [▶]
  "all_agroups" => "1"`

Comment: which input type is that adgroups? it's a checkbox or multiselect?

Comment: adroups is multiselect.
name is adgroups[] 
I tried both with adgroups and adgroups[]

Comment: and at least one must be selected? or? one group or all groups...

Comment: one should be selected.
Not both of them.

If adgrous is selected, all_adgroups should not be selected.
And opposite.

Comment: OK i got it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $this->validate($request,
        [
            'new_target_cpa_value' => 'required|numeric',
            'adgroups' => 'exists:google.ad_groups,id',
            'all_agroups' => 'required_unless:adgroups,null'
        ]
    );
```

Comment: jel radi Branko? If any of adgroups is selected the all_groups will not be required, but if none of the groups is selected then all_groups field will be required

Comment: hehe :)
gimme few min to check.

Comment: Validation rule required_unless requires at least 2 parameters. :)

maybe it would be best option for me to write custom validator rule..

Comment: can you put the value like if is null?

Comment: ill take a look little bit later, just to finish something else. 
If I make something ill post it here.

Comment: i haven't tested it.
If found this article 
http://laraveldaily.com/laravel-custom-validation-one-of-the-fields-required-but-not-both/